# Exibindo mensagens de alerta/contexto com jQuery dinamicamente além de .show(); e .hide();?

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

Durante a interação com determinada interface, veja aqui por favor no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/plan/p9d4kwuk/), algumas mensagens de alerta (nada envolvendo validação...) são apresentadas.

Minha abordagem bastante rústica para exibir/ocultar estas mensagens, e certamente também na contra mão da otimização, foi criar uma função simples que verifica se alguns checkboxes estão marcados e dependendo do contexto exibo essas mensagens extras. Entretanto, essa abordagem exige que essas mensagens já existam no DOM, daí eu poderia manipulá-las com `show();`, `hide();`, `toggle();` etc. e isso me faz pensar se existe uma maneira mais efetiva e limpa de guardar estas mensagens em uma variável / string e então dispará-las no elemento target quando preciso?

Neste exemplo eu estou tentando exibir três mensagens contextuais diferentes, uma mensagem para cada checkbox marcado, onde nesta mesma condição "marcado" um span que é o "container" das mensagens é exibido/ocultado, e uma mensagem exclusiva se 2 checkboxes (In cash e Credit Card) estiverem marcados ao mesmo tempo.

A questão é que não sou expert em JS/jQuery, mas sou curioso e estou tentando aprender na prática, então por favor não se assustem com a bagunça do código...

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
    <div class="item padding">
         <h1 class="title">Checkout</h1>

        <p>Pay in Cash or by Credit Card upon delivery</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item item-checkbox">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="#cash" name="cash">
            </label>In Cash</li>
        <li class="item item-checkbox">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="#card" name="card">
            </label>Credit Card</li>
        <li class="item item-checkbox">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="#change" name="change">
            </label>Do you Need Change?</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col">
  <div class="bar bar-balanced">
  <h1 class="title messages">
   <span class="cash-info">Conditional Info about paying In Cash</span>
   <span class="card-info">Conditional Info about paying with a Credit Card</span>
   <span class="change-info">Conditional Info about the change</span>
   <span class="pay-mix">Conditional Info about Mixed Payments</span>
 </h1>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
  // vars for conditional messages hide/display <span> with the target classes
var $conditionalCashInfo = $('.cash-info');
var $conditionalCardInfo = $('.card-info');
var $conditionalChangeInfo = $('.change-info');
var $conditionalPayMixInfo = $('.pay-mix');

// var for input checkboxes
var $cashInput = $('input[name="cash"]');
var $cardInput = $('input[name="card"]');
var $changeInput = $('input[name="change"]');

// Start by setting a few things hidden
$conditionalCashInfo.hide();
$conditionalCardInfo.hide();
$conditionalChangeInfo.hide();
$conditionalPayMixInfo.hide();
$('.bar.bar-balanced').hide();

// Any checkbox should trigger the messages box to open
        $('input[name="cash"],input[name="card"],input[name="change"]').on('click', function () { $('.bar.bar-balanced').slideDown("fast");
});

// "In Cash" checkbox actions on click + some conditional logic
$cashInput.on('click', function () {
if ($cardInput.is(':checked') == true) {
    $conditionalCashInfo.hide();
} else {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $conditionalCashInfo.fadeIn(300);
    } else {
        $changeInput.attr("checked", false);
        $conditionalChangeInfo.hide();
        $conditionalCashInfo.hide();
        $('.bar.bar-balanced').slideUp("fast");
    }
 }
});

// "Do you need change" checkbox actions on click + some conditional logic
$changeInput.on('click', function () {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $conditionalChangeInfo.fadeIn(300);
} else {
    $conditionalChangeInfo.hide();
    $('.bar.bar-balanced').slideUp("fast");
}
});

// "Credit Card" checkbox actions on click + some conditional logic
$cardInput.on('click', function () {
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $changeInput.attr("checked", false);
    $conditionalChangeInfo.hide();
    $conditionalCashInfo.hide();
    $conditionalCardInfo.fadeIn(300);

} else {
    $conditionalCardInfo.hide();
    $('.bar.bar-balanced').slideUp("fast");
    if ($cashInput.is(':checked')) {
        $conditionalCashInfo.fadeIn(300);
    }
 }
});
```

Comment: Está usando a Referência do Jquery? O quer dizer nessa linha:$conditionalCashInfo.hide();

Comment: Adriano: dá um salto aqui se tiveres tempo: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23965/small-talk

Comment: Opa @Sergio, obrigado pela atenção. Deixei lá no chat algumas considerações. att. Adriano.